# Looking for an API that returns actors/actresses info, specifically, DOB and date of death, if applicable

Tags: api, wikipedia

I'm risking downvotes on this because I don't know where else on the Stack Exchange sites to post this.

Anyways, I'm looking for a publicly available API that returns actor's/actress's information such as their date of birth, date of death, cause of death, etc.  I've been looking up and down for one but can't seem to find one.  There's always the Wikipedia API, but I'd rather not go down that route if I don't have to.  Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Have a look at http://dbpedia.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freebase! (http://www.freebase.com). Use the `mqlread` API, or the `topic` API. Specifically for what you ask for above, there's nothing specific about "actors", these are just properties of "people" (`/people/person` in Freebase nomenclature)  and "deceased people" (`/people/deceased_person`). For your specific example, the MQL query is:

```
{
  "id": "/en/heath_ledger",
  "/people/person/date_of_birth": null,
  "/people/deceased_person/date_of_death": null,
  "/people/deceased_person/cause_of_death": null
}
```

and the result:

```
{
  "result": {
    "/people/deceased_person/date_of_death": "2008-01-22",
    "/people/person/date_of_birth": "1979-04-04",
    "id": "/en/heath_ledger",
    "/people/deceased_person/cause_of_death": "Drug overdose"
  }
}
```

There are specific properties for actors (`/film/actor`) relating to film performances, Netflix IDs, etc. You can also look up by name, Wikipedia article, Netflix ID, etc.

There are obviously a million (or so...) other properties you can extract, about that person themselves and about related objects (movies they played in, e.g.).

Comment: how do you use this API?